# How can I control where Cordova CLI places the cordova.js file?

Tags: cordova, cordova-3

When I run 'cordova build', the Cordova CLI places the cordova.js file at the root of the www/ directory of whatever platform I am building for.  Is there a way I can configure it to place that file somewhere other than that location (in the www/js/ dir, perhaps)?  I know I can manually move it, but it would be nice to not have to do that each time I build.

I've noticed the .cordova/config.json file, which looks like a likely candidate for where such configuration options might be, but I haven't been able to find any documentation on the structure and/or options available to that file...

Comment: I'm not sure, but would like to know why do you want to move it?  Is it just because you want to organize all *.js files in one place, or because of some other practical reason?

Comment: Both, but the practical reason is kind of a long story, so I won't go into it here. I'll probably just write a hook for it, as that should be simple enough. It just seemed like something that would likely have a config option, but after looking through the cordova source code, it appears that it's not currently configurable.